# Formula Field Checkbox issue

Tags: formula-field, checkbox

I have created checkbox formula field. Condition is if record's owner profile is not equal to some value it should mark it as true. There are 3 profiles for which we need to check the particular value.

Initial formula is as follows:

```
IF(Case_Owner_Profile__c  <> 'Field Service', true,
IF(Case_Owner_Profile__c  <> 'Technical Support', true,  
IF(Case_Owner_Profile__c <> 'Customer Service', true, false) ) )
```

Please advise changes here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a Checkbox formula field, you do not need to explicitly set its value to *True* within the formula - all you need is for the expression itself to evaluate to *True*.

For example, instead of using the `IF` statement, just start with `Case_Owner_Profile__c <> 'Field Service'`.

When that simple statement evaluates to *True*, the checkbox should be shown as checked.

Test it with a *Field Service* Profile and a Profile that is not *Field Service*.

*A good place to start is with only one of the Profiles, and work through the logic and issues to get it to work.  Then add the other Profiles....*

---

State what you are trying to accomplish in plain language, and look for the logic words: "This checkbox should be checked when the Case Owner's Profile is **not** *Field Service* **or not** *Technical Support* **or not** *Customer Service*."

You can then work through adding to your expresion using the `OR` and `NOT` operators.

Ultimately you can try:

```
NOT(
  OR(
    Case_Owner_Profile__c = 'Field Service',
    Case_Owner_Profile__c = 'Technical Support',
    Case_Owner_Profile__c = 'Customer Service'
  )
)
```

You don't have to format it that way with the indentation and the operators on different lines; but especially at first when working through more complex logic, it can be much easier to read and follow.